# Posicionamiento del footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola mi pregunta viene a buscar una mejor respuesta que un simplemente:
Position: Absolute;
Bottom: 0px;

```
<body>
<div></div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

Yo lo que quiesiera, es que mi footer se encuentre al final de la pantalla, o en caso de que el contenido de mi div superior fuese mayor al tamaño de la pantalla, permanezca debajo de él.

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Se deduce entonces que tu div irá cambiando su altura en tiempo de ejecución. Esto implica que debe de interactuar con algo o con alguien en algún momento. La solución entonces sería aprovechar dicha interacción para relacionar el footer con el div a través de javascript. En cuanto el evento correspondiente terminara de modificar el div, javascript comprobaría las condiciones de cada caso y aplicaría el estilo css deseado: un absolute para el primer caso que describes y un flujo normal de bloque para el segundo. Para la implementación necesitaría más detalles.

Comment: Hola Sergio, exacto tenes razon. Pero en mi caso, el problema no es que el div se agrande, sino que el height de la pantalla sea menor. Es decir, como puedo condicionar segun el height de la pantalla? Media Queries?

Comment: CSS es un lenguaje cuyos efectos son, por así decirlo, estáticos. Es decir, la máquina lee el código, lo aplica y se olvida. Para volver a leer código CSS ya leído previamente la máquina necesita de otro lenguaje que le dé la orden. En este caso, es javascript. Además, CSS es un lenguaje de programación de estilos, luego no puede evaluar condiciones lógicas como "alturaPagina < alturaDiv". Para ello necesitas de otro lenguaje: javascript otra vez. A lo mejor hay alguna triquiñuela para hacer lo que quieres con CSS, pero la desconozco (seguramente sea muy rebuscada). Creo que deberás usar JS.